# Getting memory leak in SwiftUI TextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, swiftui

There is memory leak in SwiftUI TextField when I start to type in it. When I monitor this leakage using instrument I realized that the leaked object is UIDelayedAction. The leakage increase when I type more in the TextField. Is there any way to fix this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(value)
            TextField("Test", text: $value)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show it, and code. I don't observe any leaks with TextField. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2.

Comment: @Asperi I edited my question. Please check it again.

Comment: it is running on device or simulator?

Comment: @user3441734 I tested it on both.